# how to echo loop in php and put it in a variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have a problem in sending data from php to pdf. I think the only way is to put in a variable the data that will be send to pdf function.
here is the code that i need to put in a php variable..

```
<table width="95%" height="95%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                    <tr align="center">
                      <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Sun</strong></td>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Mon</strong></td>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Tue</strong></td>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Wed</strong></td>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Thu</strong></td>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Fri</strong></td>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Sat</strong></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php 
                        $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
                        $maxday    = date("t",$timestamp);
                        $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
                        $startday  = $thismonth['wday'];

                      for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
                        $day = ($i - $startday + 1);
                        if($day['1'] == '1' || $day['1'] == '2' || $day['1'] == '3' || $day['1'] == '4' || $day['1'] == '5' || $day['1'] == '6' || $day['1'] == '7' || $day['1'] == '8' || $day['1'] == '9'){
                            $day    = '0'.$day;
                        }else{
                            $day    = $day;
                        }
                        $date = $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$day.', '.$cYear;
                        $date2 = $cMonth.'/'.$day.'/'.$cYear;
                        $events = $this->getEvents($date2);
                        if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>\n";
                        if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>\n";
                        else echo "<td valign='top' align='left' width='50px' height='50px'><div class='".$dateId."' id='".$date."' title='".$date2."' style='cursor:pointer;'>". ($i - $startday + 1) .'</div>'. $events."</td>\n";
                        if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>\n";
                      }  
                     ?>
                  </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
```

Comment: Can you explain the question a bit more?

Comment: I see a lot of redundant code here.

Comment: There is no need for `else{
                            $day    = $day;
                        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible just try concatenate the loop of just put your code inside a function.
Ex.

```
function test(){
    echo '{the code}';

}

$var = test();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a huge piece of HTML/PHP and you need the output stored in a variable instead of printed to the screen, you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) functions to make this easy:

```
<?php
ob_start(); // Start the buffer (nothing will be output)
?>
```

```
<p>Lots and lots of mixed <?php echo 'HTML'; ?> and PHP...</p>
```

```
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean(); // End the buffer and assign everything to $content
?>
```

Comment: It does no show the warning anymore but the pdf output is empty.

Comment: Sounds like you have a separate problem deserving of a new question. If you do decide to ask, make sure to include your code and what PDF library you're using. I also suggest using only a small amount of sample data until you get it to work, and check the documentation of the tool you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't fully understand what you're asking I will try to answer it!

If you want everything that you are currently displaying to the page using PHP in a variable, instead of using echo, you are going to want to append that information onto your variable, so...

```
                <?php 
                    $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
                    $maxday    = date("t",$timestamp);
                    $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
                    $startday  = $thismonth['wday'];

                  for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
                    $day = ($i - $startday + 1);
                    if($day['1'] == '1' || $day['1'] == '2' || $day['1'] == '3' || $day['1'] == '4' || $day['1'] == '5' || $day['1'] == '6' || $day['1'] == '7' || $day['1'] == '8' || $day['1'] == '9'){
                        $day    = '0'.$day;
                    }else{
                        $day    = $day;
                    }
                    $date = $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$day.', '.$cYear;
                    $date2 = $cMonth.'/'.$day.'/'.$cYear;
                    $events = $this->getEvents($date2);
                    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>\n";
                    if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>\n";
                    else echo "<td valign='top' align='left' width='50px' height='50px'><div class='".$dateId."' id='".$date."' title='".$date2."' style='cursor:pointer;'>". ($i - $startday + 1) .'</div>'. $events."</td>\n";
                    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>\n";
                  }  
                 ?>
```

Would become...

```
                <?php 
                    $send_me_to_pdf = '';
                    $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
                    $maxday    = date("t",$timestamp);
                    $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
                    $startday  = $thismonth['wday'];

                  for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
                    $day = ($i - $startday + 1);
                    if($day['1'] == '1' || $day['1'] == '2' || $day['1'] == '3' || $day['1'] == '4' || $day['1'] == '5' || $day['1'] == '6' || $day['1'] == '7' || $day['1'] == '8' || $day['1'] == '9'){
                        $day    = '0'.$day;
                    }else{
                        $day    = $day;
                    }
                    $date = $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$day.', '.$cYear;
                    $date2 = $cMonth.'/'.$day.'/'.$cYear;
                    $events = $this->getEvents($date2);
                    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) $send_me_to_pdf .= "<tr>\n";
                    if($i < $startday) $send_me_to_pdf .= "<td></td>\n";
                    else $send_me_to_pdf .= "<td valign='top' align='left' width='50px' height='50px'><div class='".$dateId."' id='".$date."' title='".$date2."' style='cursor:pointer;'>". ($i - $startday + 1) .'</div>'. $events."</td>\n";
                    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) $send_me_to_pdf .= "</tr>\n";
                  }  
                 ?>
```

Now, you can use $send_me_to_pdf as an argument to your PDF functions where you want to send this data?

Answer (score 0):

Try concating variable

```
    <?php
    $var='
    <table width="95%" height="95%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                        <tr align="center">
                          <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>'.$monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear.'</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Sun</strong></td>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Mon</strong></td>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Tue</strong></td>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Wed</strong></td>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Thu</strong></td>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Fri</strong></td>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#2561cf" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>Sat</strong></td>
                        </tr>';
    ?>
                        <?php 
                            $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
                            $maxday    = date("t",$timestamp);
                            $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
                            $startday  = $thismonth['wday'];

                          for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
                            $day = ($i - $startday + 1);
                            if($day['1'] == '1' || $day['1'] == '2' || $day['1'] == '3' || $day['1'] == '4' || $day['1'] == '5' || $day['1'] == '6' || $day['1'] == '7' || $day['1'] == '8' || $day['1'] == '9'){
                                $day    = '0'.$day;
                            }else{
                                $day    = $day;
                            }
                            $date = $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$day.', '.$cYear;
                            $date2 = $cMonth.'/'.$day.'/'.$cYear;
                            $events = $this->getEvents($date2);
                            if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>\n";
                            if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>\n";
                            $var.= "<td valign='top' align='left' width='50px' height='50px'><div class='".$dateId."' id='".$date."' title='".$date2."' style='cursor:pointer;'>". ($i - $startday + 1) .'</div>'. $events."</td>\n";

if(($i % 7) == 6 ) 
$var.="</tr>\n";
                          }  

                     $var.=' </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>';

    ?>
```

Final result is in **$var**